# texture-displaced mesh with another texture for color

Tags: texturing, displacement

I am using BlenderGIS for GeoTIFF mesh import (`DEM as displacement texture` / `subsurf`) and would like to further add aerial photo to the mesh as another (RGB) texture. GeoTIFF data and the photo are alread aligned. Is it possible to define a second texture on the object which would be used for coloring the surface and retaining the elevation texture used for displacement? I am fairly new to Blender and even searching around here did not give me an asnwer. Thanks!

[image: UI shot]